# parameter wildcard expansion

Tags: linux

I have a script (let's call it script) with a file parameter.  I want the script user to be able to use wildcards in this parameter.

What do I have to use to cause the parameter variable revert to the full path?

eg script ~/*gz

So inside bash 
do x to turn variable $1 (~/*gz) into /home/name/file.tar.gz

Comment: As written, the shell will expand your parameter before passing it to the script... so if you put `echo $1` inside your script you get the expanded name (or the first name if it expands to many).

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't.  It echoes the same text I passed in.

Comment: I misread your question. I was pointing out that if you use a wildcard in your "first parameter", the shell will expand it. So if your directory contains `a.txt` and `b.txt`, and you run `script *.txt`, then the $1 parameter will contain `a.txt` NOT `*.txt`. But it seems that `readlink -f` does the trick for you. So I'm happy for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `readlink -f`. But the shell should expand the parameter, unless the wildcards are escaped. Also, does it have to be bash? why not use some scripting language like perl for that purpose?